# OpenCV for iOS graphics app

Tags: ios, opencv

I want to create a photo and video manipulation app for the iPad. The app would effect the imagery in various ways (using canny edge detection or bilateral blur for instance).

I saw some very interesting examples of canny edge detection using OpenCV, but is OpenCV the right tool to be looking into if I want to create a graphics app like this?

If so can anyone recommend some good reading materials to get me started.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can use OpenCV on iOS.  You simply cross-compile the code and include it in your project.  OpenCV can easily do what you describe, and much more.

O'Reilly has published a great book on OpenCV, which is probably the best way to get up to speed.  It explains the methods and how to use them, with plenty of sample code and images.

- [Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022497.do), Gary Bradski, Adrian Kaehler, O'Reilly 2012

There are a few sample projects around:

- [Sample OpenCV on iOS project](http://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test)

There are also numerous build scripts etc but note that they are probably not the latest version (2.4).